# Проблема с форматирование даты

Tags: java, дата, simpledateformat

почему java

```
new SimpleDateFormat("hhч mmм ssс").format(new Date(60*60*1000))
```

Выдает результат 4 часа?

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Поправка на часовой пояс.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в Вашем локальном часовом поясе. Отсчет времени идет от полуночи с 31 декабря на 1 января 1970 года по гринвичу, но Ваш часовой пояс добавляет еще 3 часа к этому времени.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте часовой пояс

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("English"));
```